# Unable to call Perl script from Java code

Tags: java, eclipse, perl, path

I am using JAX-WS in Eclipse (tomcat8 localhost) and I need to call a Perl script from it. Using the code below, I am able to reach the first three lines of Match.pl. However, when it reaches `use Stats;`, the process returns exitvalue 2.

The Stats.pm file is in the same directory as Match.pl, which has been exported to PERL5LIB with hello.sh script.

What am I doing wrong? Is there a way to use relative paths instead of absolute ones?

```
@Path("/")
public class MyService {
    @POST
    @Path("/generatePath")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public Response generatePathService(
            @FormParam("url") String fileURL) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        Process p0 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sh /home/me/workspace/MyService/hello.sh");
        p0.waitFor();
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("perl /home/me/workspace/MyService/Match.pl");
        p.waitFor();

        return Response.status(200).entity(fileURL).build();
    }
}
```

**Match.pl**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Getopt::Long;
use Stats;
```

**Stats.pm**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

package Stats;

use strict;
use warnings;
```

**hello.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

export PERL5LIB=/home/me/workspace/MyService
```

Comment: is perl in your path? Any exception?

Comment: Yes, perl is in the path (and partially runs for Match.pl). I cannot see any exceptions from Eclipse

Comment: My guess is that the export is not completed before the perl script is run

Comment: export works in the same shell, and as you are launching two different process so i don't think export will be available for the second one. Try combining both the scripts and check the result.

Comment: Combining? How can I run the export from a perl script?

Comment: Call Match.pl from hello.sh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding:

```
use FindBin;
use lib $FindBin::RealBin;
```

This will add the directory that the script is in to the library search path.

Edit: The shell script is not working  because it changes the environment of the shell process, not the Java process that spawned it.